# autoplay the contents within a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some contents within different divs that i will like to display without clicking on any tab. I have been able to toggle the visibility of these contents by clicking, but I will really prefer it to be display automatically in a loop by using jquery. Below are my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#advantages').click(function(){
         $('#featureContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
         $('#advantageContent').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden');
         $('#benefitsContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
       });

        $('#benefits').click(function(){
          $('#featureContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
          $('#advantageContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
          $('#benefitsContent').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden');
        });

        $('#features').click(function(){
        $('#featureContent').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden');
        $('#advantageContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
        $('#benefitsContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="featureLinks" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="text-center">
               <li id="features"> Smart travel </li>
               <li id="advantages"> Smart route </li>
               <li id="benefits"> Smart payment </li>
             </ul>
         </div>

    <div id="featureContent" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <h2 class="text-center"> Smart travel </h2>
           <ul>
              <li>All your favourite transit service providers like Uber, KLM, Great Western Rail and Blue Star Ferries on one integrated app! </li>
             
              <li>Compare the availability, price and ETA for taxis/buses, flights, metro andferries, anytime and anywhere.
              </li>
           </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="advantageContent" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden">
        <h2 class="text-center"> Smart Route </h2>
           <ul>
              <li> Big data is finally at your service</li>
             <li>Go where you&#39;ve never gone before with integrated Satellite navigation system.</li>
           </ul>
      </div>

       <div id="benefitsContent" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden">
       <h2 class="text-center"> Smart Payment </h2>
          <ul>
               <li> Experience the ease and security of paying via the app. </li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what would you like to trigger the event (instead of the click). ie if you want the loop to begin on document.ready remove your click functions and add a loop.

Comment: @jay lane, thanks for your response. Will you be kind enough to show this newbie(me) an example of what you mean. Thanks

Comment: see answer i just posted let me know if you need anymore help.

Answer (score 0):

@Yemmy here is a quick example this will loop over these animations 10 times until i = 10. You'll need to edit the delays so it displays as you like it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 0;
       while (i < 10){
         $('#featureContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden').delay(400);
         $('#advantageContent').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden').delay(400);
         $('#benefitsContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden').delay(400);



          $('#featureContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden').delay(400);
          $('#advantageContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden').delay(400);
          $('#benefitsContent').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden').delay(400);



        $('#featureContent').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden').delay(400);
        $('#advantageContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden').delay(400);
        $('#benefitsContent').fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden').delay(400);
        i++
       };
    });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nn4hgrv2/#&togetherjs=kcgRhDRIGb

Comment: no problem. if you don't mind just mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.setInterval` to call a function repeatedly, asynchronously, on a timer.  I have shown an example in the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var rotateElements = [ $('#featureContent'), $('#advantageContent'), $('#benefitsContent') ];
       var displayedIndex = 0;

       window.setInterval( function() {
         if (displayedIndex > rotateElements.length) displayedIndex = 0;
         
         for (var i = 0; i < rotateElements.length; ++i) {
           if (i == displayedIndex)
             rotateElements[i].fadeIn(400).removeClass('hidden');
           else
             rotateElements[i].fadeOut(400).addClass('hidden');
         }
         
         displayedIndex++;
        }, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="featureLinks" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="text-center">
               <li id="features"> Smart travel </li>
               <li id="advantages"> Smart route </li>
               <li id="benefits"> Smart payment </li>
             </ul>
         </div>

    <div id="featureContent" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <h2 class="text-center"> Smart travel </h2>
           <ul>
              <li>All your favourite transit service providers like Uber, KLM, Great Western Rail and Blue Star Ferries on one integrated app! </li>
             
              <li>Compare the availability, price and ETA for taxis/buses, flights, metro andferries, anytime and anywhere.
              </li>
           </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="advantageContent" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden">
        <h2 class="text-center"> Smart Route </h2>
           <ul>
              <li> Big data is finally at your service</li>
             <li>Go where you&#39;ve never gone before with integrated Satellite navigation system.</li>
           </ul>
      </div>

       <div id="benefitsContent" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden">
       <h2 class="text-center"> Smart Payment </h2>
          <ul>
               <li> Experience the ease and security of paying via the app. </li>
         </ul>
</div>
```